# Commercial YAML Parsers for C#

Tags: c#, .net, yaml

Did look at the open source parsers for C# from the YAML wikipedia, but they are not actively developed.

- [Yaml Library for .NET (C#)](http://yaml-net-parser.sourceforge.net/)
- [YAML Parser in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/yamlparser.aspx) (an almost feature complete YAML Parser written in C#)
- [YAML for .NET, Visual Studio and
  Power shell](http://www.codeplex.com/yaml)

Are there any commercial options?

Comment: I know this doesn't address the direct question, but you do have incredibly fast XMLSerialization that is trivial to use. If it turns out that you need an external dependency to get it then why complicate things for a different text format?

Comment: "incredibly fast"? I don't think so: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance

Comment: Did you see http://yamlserializer.codeplex.com/?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you must use a YAML parser instead of just using the built in .NET serialization? I'm not finding any implementations beyond those you posted.